# Dynamically allocating struct vector

Tags: c, memory, struct, dynamic

I have created the following struct:

```
typedef struct move {
        char line;
        int column;
}move;
```

And want to dynamically allocate memory for an array of this previous struct.
What I have so far is:

```
int main(){
        //Allocate memory for 1 move
        struct move *moves = malloc(sizeof(struct move));
        printf("Moves size: %ld\n", sizeof(moves));
        //Read first move
        scanf("%c%d", &moves->line, &moves->column);
        printf("Move 1 = %c%d\n", moves->line, moves->column);
        //Realloc moves so that struct vector can fit 2 moves now
        moves = (struct move*)realloc(moves, sizeof(moves) + sizeof(struct move));
        printf("Moves size after realloc: %ld\n", sizeof(moves));
        //Read second move
        scanf("%c%d", &(moves+1)->line, &(moves+1)->column);
        printf("Move 1 = %c%d\n", (moves+1)->line, (moves+1)->column);
        return 0;
}
```

With this I'm able to read the first move but not the second one. I think I'm not doing the realloc part correctly, but I also have a feeling my struct should have some sort of pointer that points to the next move.

I saw some similar questions here regarding similar issues but all of the structs had pointers inside.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `sizeof(moves)` is the size of the pointer, which is irrelevant. The only thing relevant is the size of `struct move`.

Comment: Than how can I see the size of the struct array?

Comment: You did not declare a "struct array". To declare `moves` to be an array of type `struct move` with two elements, you must write `struct move moves[2];`. Afterwards, you can get the size of that array with the expression `sizeof(moves)`. By instead writing `struct move *moves = malloc(sizeof(struct move))`, you are not declaring an array, but merely a pointer that points to an address in memory with sufficient space for one element of `struct move`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
        char line;
        int column;
}move;

int main()
{
        char ch;

        move *moves = malloc(sizeof(move));
        if(!moves)
            exit(1);

        scanf("%c%d", &moves->line, &moves->column);
        printf("Move 1 = %c%d\n", moves->line, moves->column);

        moves = (move*)realloc(moves, sizeof(move)*2);
        if(!moves)
            exit(1);

       while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&&ch!=EOF);
       scanf("%c%d", &(moves+1)->line, &(moves+1)->column);
       printf("Move 1 = %c%d\n", (moves+1)->line, (moves+1)->column);
       return 0;
}
```

This will print size of moves(size of pointer) not what it pointing to

```
      printf("Moves size: %ld\n", sizeof(moves));
```

So you can remove this if you want put *moves but it prints size of one "move" only (i.e current pointing move) not all "move" it points to.And change something in realloc and flush stdin by the while loop and you need to check does malloc is memory allocated or not

Comment: Note, you need to include parenthesis around `(c = getchar()) != '\n'` and you also need to check the return of every input function. [Henry Spencer's 10 Commandments for C Programmers - No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) *"Ye be warned..."*